# What does () sign mean in this nested Record ? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, immutable.js

What does () sign mean in this nested Record using immutable.js?

This is the code:

```
'use strict'

const {Record} = require('immutable')

const Form = Record({
  disabled: false,
  fields: new (Record({
    username: '',
    usernameHasError: false,
    email: '',
    emailHasError: false,
    password: '',
    passwordHasError: false,
    passwordAgain: '',
    passwordAgainHasError: false,
    showPassword: false
  }))()
})
```

At the the of the `fields` there is extra `()` sign, what does it mean? What syntax is it?

Comment: `()` is the syntax to call a function without passing any parameters.

Comment: In the code case, why is there a function? shouldnt it contain only state record?

Comment: [`Record`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) returns a function which is being immediately invoked by the `new (....)()` syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an immediately invoking function expression(IIFE). Such function will be be immediately executed.

When a function is wrapped in `()` that acts as a function expression. The `()` acts like calling that function expression.

An example of IIFE

```js
(function() {
  console.log('I am an IIFE')
})();
```

Comment: so on my code case, it immediately invoke Record function?